# Error while loading Crystal Report in Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am having the following error while generating report for one of my application. I'm using Visual Studio 2005 in Windows 7 64-bit.

The 'crdb_dao.dll' is a 32-bit dll. I have googled it for 64-bit but have not found anything.

Also I have read other forums where authors have suggested that only loading this dll into the project will not solve this problem.

Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems there was some problem with report design. After I recreated report, error seems to be resolved.